# JavaFX（Java 9）で Meiryo UI が使えない？

Tags: javafx

Java9でJavaFXのアプリケーションを開発してみているのですが、
Java8ではできていたフォントを「Meiryo UI」にすることが、Java9ではできなくなっています。
（Scene Builder も Scene Builder for Java 9 を使っています）

Scene Builderのバグかなと思ってとりあえず、cssで

```
-fx-font-family: 'Meiryo UI';
```

と指定してみましたが、
実行したアプリケーションのフォントは、「Meiryo UI」ではなく「メイリオ」になってしまいました。

Java 9から、Meiryo UIは使えなくなったのでしょうか？

[image: Java8の環境では Meiryo UI が選択できます]
[image: Java9の環境では Meiryo UI が選択できません]

Answer (score 1):

Scene Builder 9を実行して、ButtonおよびTextをレイアウトに貼り、それらのPropertiesでFont欄 から Family のリストボックスでフォント一覧をポップアップしたところ、Meiryo UIおよびMeiryoともに表示されました。

また、PropertiesのJavaFX CSSカテゴリのStyle欄に

```
-fx-font-family   'Meiryo UI'
```

と設定してみたところ、Meiryo UI フォントで表示されました。

OSはWindows 10 です。